# Output same content type in different format

Tags: 6

I need to output a same content type in 2 formats : html and xml. How can I do that and what url to use o access these different outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to use [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) which allows you to output any data in XML, JSON, XHTML with different schemas. You can the set your own URLs and can have fine control over the output.

Another, rather primitive way is to use the RSS feed with full content on, but I take it that may not be what you are looking for, yet when all else fails — it is better than nothing.

Comment: Thks!!It's a very good solution